# Macbook Pro (2010, OSX Sierra) has started prompting me to enter password for DHCP again and again and again

Tags: network, macos, security, virus

All of a sudden my mac has started prompting me to enter my password with the dialog: "Network Configuration needs to update DHCP setting. Type your password to allow this."

[image]

I've just recently installed MakeMKV on my laptop... could my Mac have caught something nasty?

As a side note: Is there a way I can find out which process is creating the pop-up window?

Comment: If I click cancel, the window just re-appears immediately...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a trojan! 
Look at the Directory ~/Library/VideoFrameworks
The Trojan collected your keychain and browser-data there.

The program itself resides in ~/Library/RenderFiles

You can stop it with
launchctl stop fr.handbrake.activity_agent

Did you install handbrake as well or just makemkv?

I would recommend to make a clean install of osx or install your time-machine backup from before the installation of the program.

Update: I cannot comment here, so I try to edit my answer with additional information:

The trojan collects at least the following data:

- Keychain files (saved passwords in OSX)
- Personal data from every browser on your system including saved passwords
- Screenshots

So you really should check which passwords you saved in the keychain and the browser and change them immediately on another computer. You can find the data that it collected in the directory described above in several zip-files.

Do you remember where you downloaded handbrake? Did you use the update function?

Comment: Bugger! Yeah I did install Handbrake too.... :( Thanks Dave, ugh, I was hoping to be able to avoid a re-install...

Comment: Same, just got Handbrake and it asked for my password to install extra codecs, now the DHCP setting box won't go away. Nuts.

Comment: I have neither of the files you/directories you listed. How did you know those were the ones, I might use the same method to find the ones being used on my system

Comment: you can execute "launchctl list" to see a list of services. The service that shows the dialog about needing to update the dhcp settings is called fr.handbrake.activity_agent. And have a look at ~/Library/LaunchAgents. "launchctl list fr.handbrake.activity_agent" gives information about the service.

Comment: Now the developers of handbrake announced, that a mirror-server was compromised. You might have got the same by updating an older version with the built in updater https://forum.handbrake.fr/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=36364

Comment: Thanks Dave. I know I got the infected code, but I still don't have the RenderFiles or VideoFrameworks folders. If I knew how you found them I'd be able to find the equivalent folders on my machine

Comment: Did you try the launchctl-commands on the console that i described above? That's how I found the RenderFiles directory. Additionally do a "cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents" and "ls -la" to see if there is a plist-file that starts the service. Do you still have the dhcp-dialog?

Comment: I restarted the computer to get rid of the dialog and turned off network access as soon as I realised it was compromised. I have not started Handbrake since then. No reference to Handbrake appears when I use the launchctl command, and LaunchAgents is empty. It's OS X 10.8.5, perhaps it is too old for the Trojan

Comment: I cannot tell how it behaves on other systems, but chances are that it deleted the files after it was successful. You might check if you have the following files in the /tmp directory: au, au.pub, public.pem. But the directory gets cleared after a reboot. You could also look after traces of "activity_agent" in the system-log (start console-app). For example under "User Diagnostic reports". I found a crash-log there.

Comment: Cool. No sign of any of that and nothing that the Handbrake forum announcement covered either, so I may have escaped. XProtect version at 2087. Still, time for a clean slate I think.